# Spotfire : Load already created pickle file from data function in spotfire

Tags: python, pickle, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

Has anyone tried calling in a pickle file already created from spotfire's data function?
There is too little information about using pickle file from data function.
If anyone has used it, please provide a simple example of calling the pickle file from the path of the local pc and using it.

I searched spotfire pickle on Google and tried the results but failed.
I'd like to refer to an example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from within a Spotfire Python data function as you would normally in Python, there is nothing special about it, unless you do not have access to the file system where your pickle file is. So something like the following should work:

```
import pickle
filename = "your file path"
with open(filename, 'rb') as f: 
    mydata = pickle.load(f)
```

where 'your file path' is the path to the pickle file. If you know the names of variables in your pickle file, you can put them in a comma separated list instead of mydata.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you take the Python server and the webplayer server separately, if you run it on the web browser through the link, the data function will run on the Python server. Do you know what path I need to put the pickle file in to bring it up?

Comment: I'm not sure, guessing the same server that Python runs on.